# How to refresh a blazor sub/child component within a main/parent component?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

You have a main component and inside the main component you have many sub-components

You want to refresh a single subcomponent, rather than the entire screen of the main component, is this possible?

Comment: You can ask the sub component to refresh by calling its `StateHasChanged` method

Comment: @aguafrommars In the @code section of a .razor page, how to refer to a particular sub-component? Is there a Blazor counterpart to ASP.NET's `Page.FindControl()`?

Comment: @Tim You can get a reference of the component you want using `@ref` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#capture-references-to-components

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

**Parent.razor**

```
<Child @ref="_childComponent" />
<button @onclick="@(() => _childComponent.Refresh())">Refresh Child</button>

@code {
    private Child _childComponent;
}
```

**Child.razor**

```
<p>Right now: @DateTime.Now</p>

@code {
    public void Refresh()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```