# Refresh blazor server child component from parent component by using StateHasChanged

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor relaod child component

One of my component is like below ( This is a child component in my case )

ListMetaData component / Child Component

```
  <table>
        bind the list of items from model to the table
  </table>

@code {
   
    List<MetaDataViewModel> model= new List<MetaDataViewModel>();    
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadMetaDataList();
    }
    public async Task  LoadMetaDataList()
    {        
        model= dbContextService.fetchFromDb();
    }    
    public void Refresh()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I have a parent component and it is like below

```
@page "/settings/metadata"
@inject IDialogService DialogService
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar
<MudGrid>
<MudItem  >
   <MudButton OnClick="@((e) => AddNewmetaDataEvent())" 
    Class="ma-1">Add new</MudButton>
</MudItem>
<MudItem xs="12" >
    <ListMetaData  @ref="_listComponent" ></ListMetaData>
</MudItem>
</MudGrid>
@code {
     private ListMetaData  _listComponent;
    async Task AddNewmetaDataEvent()
    {
        var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddMetaDataDialog>("Add new MetaData");
        var result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {           
             Snackbar.Add("Please wait while the list is getting updated", Severity.Info);
             _listComponent.Refresh();             
        }
        else
        {
              Snackbar.Add("Dialog cancelled without performing any action", Severity.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

From parent component on button click event a dialog is appearing and allowing user to add new item to the database.

On close of dialog i am trying to reload the list of items in child component

But the list is not getting updated for me even after using StateHasChanged(). I have to reload the page to see the modified list of items in the child component

I followed  couple of answers from community [How to refresh a blazor sub/child component within a main/parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226890/how-to-refresh-a-blazor-sub-child-component-within-a-main-parent-component) but not getting what is not correct in my code

Comment: You have wrapped the AddNewmetaDataEvent method in an `async void` contruct. Just use `OnClick="AddNewmetaDataEvent"`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (however see the notes)

```
@page "/settings/metadata"
@inject IDialogService DialogService
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

 <MudItem  >
   <MudButton OnClick="@((e) => AddNewmetaDataEvent())" 
    Class="ma-1">Add new</MudButton>
 </MudItem>

@if (_updating)
{
<span>Updating</span>
}
else
    {
<MudGrid>

   <MudItem xs="12" >
    <ListMetaData  @ref="_listComponent" ></ListMetaData>
</MudItem>
</MudGrid>        
 }



@code {
    private ListMetaData  _listComponent;
    private bool _updating;
    async Task AddNewmetaDataEvent()
    {
        _updating = true; // forces UI dom refresh

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddMetaDataDialog>("Add new MetaData");
        var result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {           
             Snackbar.Add("Please wait while the list is getting updated", Severity.Info);
        }
        else
        {
              Snackbar.Add("Dialog cancelled without performing any action", Severity.Normal);
        }
        _updating = false; // forces UI dom refresh
    }
}
```

Try to avoid updating the child components by capturing the reference. I am aware that UI libraries like SyncFusion etc force this kind of @ref / Refresh() pattern. Avoid it as much as possible and instead pass on the data as parameter . That will save you from these type of manual refreshes.

Comment: Pass data as parameter to Child component? In my case child component is for showing list and what parameter we have to pass? A flag to decide reload or not?
Also in the answer do we need to call Refresh()? I cant see that is mentioned anywhere

Comment: In the if ... else statement, one of the block is rendered. When the 'updating' flag is true, the MudGrid component is removed from DOM. When it is set to false, the MudGrid component is rendered from scratch. So you don't need to manually refresh anything. Also, on ChildComponent question, you should send the List to your child component.  (I am updating the answer a little bit because it might cause runtime issues.)

Comment: I agree with the answer, `await LoadMetaDataList();` should not be inside the ListMetaData  component but in the parent. And then `<ListMetaData  data=listData />` solves all update problems.